# Why it gives unexpected results when pass * as main method argument?

Tags: java

I have come across an interesting point. I have created a simple java file which take arguments from command line and do the arithmetic operation provided,

```
e.g. java Test 2 3 5 + This gives output as 10 correctly
```

But when I tried 
`java Test 2 3 *` 
it throws `NumberFormatException`. Then I looked what are the values that get pass as arguments and saw that all file names in the folder (where my java file is) is getting pass as arguments.

Is this a typical scenario?

My code is

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int x = 1; x < args.length - 1; x++) {
            int y = Integer.parseInt(args[x]);

            if (args[args.length - 1].equals("+")) {
                sum += y;
            } else if (args[args.length - 1].equals("-")) {
                sum -= y;
            } else if (args[args.length - 1].equals("*")) {
                sum *= y;
            } else if (args[args.length - 1].equals("/")) {
                sum /= y;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you on a unix-ish system/environment? `*` would be interpreted as a wildcard by the shell and expanded into any filenames in the current directory, so you might actually be calling `java 2 3 file1 file2 file3 etc...` having `java 2 3 \*` would fix the problem

Comment: To avoid this, you'll need to do `java Test 2 3 '*'`

Comment: * is a not a number.  You are trying yo parse it in int

Comment: @MarcB I'm running on Windows 7

Comment: Java is emulating the unix-style glob expansion on Windows when you run the program with arguments containing `?` or `*`. But on Windows you have to use double-quotes to avoid expansion, i.e. `"*"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shell is doing [glob expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). You can fix this by quoting:

```
java Test 2 3 '*'
```